# Use Blazor server-side from an ASP.NET Framework monolith

Tags: asp.net, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, razor-components

In my company we still use an ASP.NET Framework website with a lot of different controllers and views (monolith). Now I was wondering how I can replace some of those views with Blazor server-side (as a Razor-component package). It is possible to run a new ASP.NET Core instance (with Blazor server-side and their Razor-components) next to the monolith. I was wondering how I can easily and properly forward traffic from the monolith to the Blazor views and how I can easily forward the websockets-communication. If this is possible, I could strip down the old monolith by replacing the views with Razor-components, step-by-step.